# SQL summations with multiple outer joins

Tags: sql

I have tables a, b, c, and d whereby:

```
There are 0 or more b rows for each a row
There are 0 or more c rows for each a row
There are 0 or more d rows for each a row
```

If I try a query like the following:

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(b.debit), SUM(c.credit), SUM(d.other)
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.a_id
LEFT JOIN c on a.id = c.a_id
LEFT JOIN d on a.id = d.a_id
GROUP BY a.id
```

I notice that I have created a cartesian product and therefore my sums are incorrect (much too large).

I see that there are other SO questions and answers, however I'm still not grasping how I can accomplish what I want to do in a single query.  Is it possible in SQL to write a query which aggregates all of the following data:

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(b.debit)
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.a_id
GROUP BY a.id

SELECT a.id, SUM(c.credit)
FROM a
LEFT JOIN c on a.id = c.a_id
GROUP BY a.id

SELECT a.id, SUM(d.other)
FROM a
LEFT JOIN d on a.id = d.a_id
GROUP BY a.id
```

in a single query?

Comment: Oh wait, I suppose I could UNION three subqueries and do grouping with THAT outer query...

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ID, debit, credit, other
FROM a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a_id, SUM(b.debit) as debit
           FROM b
          GROUP BY a_id) b  ON a.ID = b.a_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a_id, SUM(b.credit) as credit
           FROM c
          GROUP BY a_id) c  ON a.ID = c.a_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a_id, SUM(b.other) as other
           FROM d
          GROUP BY a_id) d  ON a.ID = d.a_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is correct. Unrelated `JOIN` create cartesian products.

You have to do the sums separately and then do a final addition. This is doable in one query and you have several options for that:

- Sub-requests in your SELECT: `SELECT a.id, (SELECT SUM(b.debit) FROM b WHERE b.a_id = a.id) + ...`
- `CROSS APPLY` with a similar query as the first bullet then `SELECT a.id, b_sum + c_sum + d_sum`
- `UNION ALL` as you suggested with an outer `SUM` and `GROUP BY` on top of that.
- `LEFT JOIN` to similar subqueries as above.

And probably more... The performance of the various solutions might be slightly different depending on how many rows in `A` you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done with correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT a.id
     , (SELECT SUM(debit) FROM b WHERE a.id = b.a_id)
     , (SELECT SUM(credit) FROM c WHERE a.id = c.a_id)
     , (SELECT SUM(other) FROM d WHERE a.id = d.a_id)
 FROM a
```

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected this was the case but the proprietary library I'm using has limited support for even the most basic subqueries.